# Upgrading CPU AMD Socket F

Tags: upgrade, cpu-architecture, opteron

I was wondering if it were possible to upgrade an Opteron 2356, to an Opteron 8439SE?  Both can use Socket F(r2/Fr5/Fr6),  but I'm a little nervous about the quad core to hex core move....

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For hardware compatibility, you should check with the server vendor (or motherboard vendor if this is an assembled computer).

For O.S. support, there shouldn't be any problem: all modern OSes can handle a change in the number of CPUs/cores without any issue.